# spring-data-mongodb java driver 3.x api adoption

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I'm wondering if there are any plans to adopt the "non-legacy" mongo java driver 3.x api (i.e. the classes in com.mongodb.client, MongoDatabase, MongoCollection, etc.) in spring-data-mongodb at some point. MongoOperation.execute(DbCallback) forces you into the legacy mongo java driver api, and it's unfortunate to not be able to follow the latest mongodb java driver documentation at http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/driver/reference/. Per https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#java-driver-compatibility, the 3.2 java driver is compatible with all recent versions of mongodb. Is there a reason spring-data-mongodb is still using the 2.x driver and/or the legacy api classes (com.mongodb.DB, com.mongodb.DBCollection, etc)?